# MySQL Random Query Generator Output meaning

Tags: mysql, perl, testing, percona

I have downloaded the MySQ Random Query Generator (RQG) that i am testing on my percona 5.6 server. However, i do not know what to make of my results when i run a test. Can somebody help me understand the meaning of my output, and maybe what results i should be expecting? I am new to RQG and i cannot find a good tutorial online that discusses how to interpret the output, or even what to expect when you run a test.

Test command for Percona server5.6:

```
perl gentest.pl --dsn=dbi:mysql:host=192.168.2.100:port=3306:user=root:password=skret:database=test --threads=1 --queries=100K --grammar=conf/percona_qa/5.6/5.6.yy --duration 3600
```

Output

```
# 2015-09-14T10:16:55 -------------------------------
# 2015-09-14T10:16:55 Configuration
# 2015-09-14T10:16:55   debug_server => ['']
# 2015-09-14T10:16:55   dsn => ['dbi:mysql:host=192.168.2.100:port=3306:user=root:password=skret:database=test']
# 2015-09-14T10:16:55   duration => 3600
# 2015-09-14T10:16:55   generator => FromGrammar
# 2015-09-14T10:16:55   grammar => conf/percona_qa/5.6/5.6.yy
# 2015-09-14T10:16:55   queries => 100000
# 2015-09-14T10:16:55   reporters => ['']
# 2015-09-14T10:16:55   seed => 1
# 2015-09-14T10:16:55   threads => 1
# 2015-09-14T10:16:55   transformers => ['']
# 2015-09-14T10:16:55   validators => ['']
# 2015-09-14T10:16:55   views => ['', '']
# 2015-09-14T10:16:55 Reporters: ErrorLog, Backtrace
```

Comment: I need to download this too. It will improve my normal queries, and save me the effort

Comment: Drew, you can download from https://launchpad.net/randgen/+download

Comment: Thank you sir I certainly will

Comment: your DB is bombarded with a lot of random queries within a short period of time. I think you should expect some failure message if it cannot handle this load, the test running through is good news in and of itself.

Comment: @Bytepusher, but it seems after producing the last line (Repoters: ErrorLog, Backtrace], it just hang there, even if i set duration to time of 360 seconds. Shouldn't somehow stop after the indicated duration? And what should i interpret "Reporters: ErrorLog, Backtrace" anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are testing with only one server, like percona 5.6 you used, the only possible output from the randomly generated queries is when the random query fails with ERROR message. At this time, RQG will print these error situation on the console.

If it encounters no error at all, it will run silently until query count reach the "--queries" you specified, or the time specified is out. The timeout value in your example is 3600 seconds, which is one hour.

Actually, from my own experience using RQG, the most powerful way for me is using RQG to compare two different servers, specified in --dsn1 and --dsn2.
In this case, when the generated random query get different result from the two servers, it will print out the mismatched result.
Using this kinds comparison, even dozens of bugs in MySQL 5.6 and 5.7 are found, after they are released.